# AT commands (Hayes commands) in Android app without root

Tags: android, at-command, modem

Is it possible to send AT commands (aka Hayes command set) in Android app on a non rooted device? The information I need (cell channel) is only available in response of AT command, so I need to find a way to get it.

I know that this can be done with ADB shell and su, but how to send AT commands in an Android app?

Comment: Which GSM kit are you using?

Comment: @Jay, what do you mean? I want to get this info on a casual phone (like Nexus 6). But if it is possible only on MTK phones, I will be glad to know about it too.

Comment: Can you communicate with the modem via serial port? For instance, on my Samsung devices, I enable modem by setting DM + MODEM + ADB from *#0808# menu.